# Is it possible to make curves more visible in the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view, bezier-curves

I'm trying to edit a camera path and a camera follow path, but I'm finding it quite hard to see the curves. Is there a way to change their color or make them thicker? I've also seen screenshots that show frame numbers along the curves—how do I enable that?

Comment: You can temporarily apply bevel on those curves to make them thick; they will become renderable but for viewport testing it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Mr Zak suggested, you can give the curve in question a bevel object. You can adjust the thickness of the curve by scaling it.

Just switch off render for both of them and it shouldn't affect your scene.

[image]